# Postactivate script for auto-changing to project directory

Tags: bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, virtualenv-commands

I have a one-line entry in my virtualenv `postactivate` script which notifies my of which virtualenv I'm in:

```
export PS1="\[\033[40;1;36m\](`basename $VIRTUAL_ENV`)\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;34m\] \W\[\033[00m\] \$ "
```

I want to add a line which will also change into the directory of my project when I issue the workon command. This is only for me really, so I am happy to issue the command `workon myproject` and use myproject as the only variable and then change to `/path/to/projects/myproject`. This will work as all my projects are in the same directory. To demonstrate:

```
cd ~/projects/django-projects/$1
```

Would work, but of course the command variable is actually `post_activate`. Can I easily grab the string from the command line and pass it to this script?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: ok `dir=${VIRTUAL_ENV:17}; cd ~/projects/django-projects/$dir` worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it, hough I think there are various solutions:

```
dir=${VIRTUAL_ENV:17}; cd ~/projects/django-projects/$dir
```

Comment: I this is better for getting virtual environment name: `dir=$(basename $VIRTUAL_ENV);`

Comment: Why not simply `cd "$VIRTUAL_ENV"`?